# Get call duration of active calls in Asterisk 13

Tags: asterisk

Please, I want to implement billing in asterisk 13.

i want to be able monitor an active call of a particular extension ( say  extension 0001) and Hangup call once the extension have used 10mins. How do I achieve this in dailplan ( i.e extensions.conf)

...appreciations for any input.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i can recommend you use already created billings like a2billing.org or CCGrates.

If you have not much resources and experience, that will be just wast of time(alot of things can go not as you expect).

For see currently active calls you can use ForkCDR functions of CEL events(like some commercial billing systems use).

You also can use AMI events+dialplan for track that(like fop/fop2 use), but tat is not easy way.

Most easy way is CEL probably.

For hangup call you can use function TIMEOUT(absolute) or params of Dial command.